# Conditional HTML tag on Body tag

Tags: asp.net-core

On an ASP.NET Core 2.1 view I have the following:

```
<div @{if (1==1) { <text>style="background-image: url('image.png')"</text> }}></div>
```

Note: I am using 1==1 just for testing ...

This renders fine but I need to apply this to body tag:

```
<body @{if (1==1) { <text>style="background-image: url('image.png')"</text> }}>
```

In this case I get the error:

```
The tag helper 'body' must not have C# in the element's attribute declaration area.
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are writing doesn't seem to result in valid HTML.

Here are a few ideas (in order of complexity) to get you started.

**Traditional conditional**

```
<body>
    @if (1 == 1)
    {
        <div style="background-image: url('image.png')"></div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div></div>
    }
</body>
```

**Ternary Operator**

```
<div style="@((1 == 1) ? "background-image: url('image.png')" : "")"></div>
```

**Move logic to separate block**

```
@{
    var divStyle = "";
    if (1 == 1)
    {
        divStyle = "background-image: url('image.png')";
    }
}

<div style="@divStyle"></div>
```

**Logic done server side and stored in model**

```
@model MyViewModel

<div style="@Model.DivStyle"></div>
```

**Inject service into View (Dependency Injection)**

```
@inject StyleService _styleService

<div style="@_styleService.GetStyleIfTrue(1 == 1)"></div>
```